# This ajax url is good but is noticing me GET 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-status-code-404, google-chrome-console

I trying to do a validation by ajax and php, this is my ajax code:

```
function PrintRecibopapel()
{
    recibo = document.getElementById("txtCod").value;

    if(recibo == "")
        {
            alert("Debe Guardar el recibo antes de imprimir");
        }
    else
    {               
        //ImprimirPDF("modulos/reporte/ingresos/RPrintReciboPapel.php?cods="+recibo);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'modulos/ingresos/actualizarIngreso.php',
            data: {recibo: recibo}
        })
    } 

    }
```

The function `PrintRecibopapel();` is in my form on an input with onclick

So, this is my php (other file):

```
<?php

include("../../libreria/engine.php");

$_SESSION["logError"] = array();

$recibo = $_GET["recibo"];

$sql = "UPDATE af_ing SET copia = 1 WHERE cod = '$recibo'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<script languaje= 'javascript'>
mostrarErrores();
actualizarPestana();
</script>
```

The error that the Google Chrome console is givin to me is this: `VM2941:1 GET http://localhost/municipia1/modulos/ingresos/actualizarIngreso.php?recibo=2017-00090 404 (Not Found)`

As you can see (at least me) is that the url is good and is passing the variable `recibo` fine, Do I am doing something wrong?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Are both of these in `municipal`?

Comment: "As you can see (at least me) is that the url is good" — We can only see that the server says "Not Found". All the evidence we have says the URL is not good.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Just put the URL in a browser and press enter. It's not that hard.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sure, both are in the same folder. Thank you! This mysql is obsolete i will fix it.

Comment: What is the URL you are running this script from?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  http://localhost/municipia1/modulos/ingresos/cobro.php

Comment: If that is the address you're running it from change the url in the AJAX to `url: 'actualizarIngreso.php',` because the AJAX call is looking for those directories *below* your starting point.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, i will. Thank you. I am a new at programming and here, so sorry for the english grammar (not my native language) and all the newbie question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX paths to server-side scripts can either be relative or absolute. In this case you are making the AJAX call from the same directory location in which the server-side script lives. Since you are running both scripts from the same directory it would be easier to use a relative path and change the URL in your AJAX call to this:

```
url: 'actualizarIngreso.php',
```

As it stands now the AJAX call is looking for the following *which is wrong* and generates the 404 error:

> municipia1/modulos/ingresos/municipia1/modulos/ingresos/actualizarIngreso.php

Many times developers will develop a central library of server-side scripts and put them in one location where they can receive calls from many locations. In that case you can use absolute path in your AJAX `url` parameter:

```
url: 'http://hostname/municipia1/modulos/ingresos/actualizarIngreso.php',
```

Comment: Glad to help @I.Valera